# ReactJS Datepicker - I want the datepicker to start from this month and on only

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, react-datepicker

How can I make that [ReactJS Datepicker](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/#example-8) should only display days starting from this month and on (no back dates).

Answer (score 2):

**This is not exactly what I was trying to do but its a quick fix.**

I use the  `includeDates={this.state.includeDates}` from [ReactJS Datepicker](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/#example-13)

and I made a custom function to print out the days starting from today and i save it in an array that i then pass to the react state `excludeDates: ['']`,
and only those days will be clickable.

```
let fromDate = moment();
let toDate = moment().add(24, 'months'); //including only days starting from today untill 2 year
            for (let i = 0; i < moment(toDate).diff(fromDate, 'days') + 1; i++) {
                state.includeDates.push(moment(fromDate).add(i, 'days'));

}
```

Thanl you! hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment [`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) using `'month'` parameter to get the first day of the month and pass it to `minDate` option to make the datepicker enable only dates from the start of the current month:

```html
<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  minDate={moment().startOf('month')}
/>
```

If you want to enable only future dates, simply remove maxDate option from the linked example, you can use the following code:

```html
<DatePicker
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  minDate={moment().startOf('day')}
/>
```